# Minifying httpInterceptor AngularJS $injector error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

When I minify/obfuscate/uglify my code, my `httpInterceptor` is not working anymore.

I get the following error :

```
Error: error:unpr
Unknown Provider

Unknown provider: aProvider <- a
```

My code with all irrelevant stuff removed:

```
angular.module("MyApp").factory('sessionChecker', ['$q', '$injector',
    function ($q, $injector) {
        var sessionRecoverer = {
            responseError: function (response) {
                // Session has expired
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    var $location = $injector.get('$location');
                    var $modal = $injector.get('$modal');
                    $location.path("/login");

                } else if (response.status === 500) {
                    var $location = $injector.get('$location');
                    //Do stuff..
                } else if (response.status === 0) {
                    var $modal = $injector.get('$modal');
                    //Do stuff..
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
        return sessionRecoverer;
    }]);

angular.module("MyApp").config(['$httpProvider',
    function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionChecker');
    }]);
```

How would I inject my dependencies correctly, or am I missing something? This is working fine without minifying my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `aProvider` doesn't exist in the source code you have shown, why are you using the `$injector` to inject things, that can be injected through the constructor...

Comment: The error is after minifying..

Comment: I don't see how your minifier is doing that, seeing as everything looks to me to be fine.

Comment: I don't know how my minfier is doing that. It gives weird angular errors on minified code.. I get what you say about using the $injector, but if I try injecting through the constructor I get a 'Circular Dependency' error. Minified or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it is this piece of code that is generating the error? (This code looks OK to me...) But this error is definitely caused by not using the `['dep1', dep2', function(dep1,dep2){...}]` syntax (or equivalent with `$inject`).

You can try the strict DI mode so that Angular will report the error in *non*-minified mode ([ref here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production)):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```

Or (if bootstrapping manually):

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'], {
    strictDi: true
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the code that is generating this error. This fires as soon as I lose connection to my server (i.e. pulling the internet cable from the LAN port), and that is exactly when this error pops, thus failing the code to execute (showing a modal).

Comment: You are using the `$modal`; you are probably defining a controller which uses the simplified injection pattern. It is in the 2nd `//Do stuff..` part...

Comment: You, my friend, are a hero. You even find mistakes in code I didn't post. My apologies for that. It was exactly what you said.. I used simplified injection on the $modal, thinking it was not needed at that point.. Meet my lazy brain..

Comment: Have found myself in exactly the same situation :)